# Upgrading rails 5.0 to rails 6.0.1 - existing app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I recently tried to update to Rails 6 and it won't seem to work. I switched it over in my gemfile from 5.0 and updated the gemfile.lock as required.

```
Step1: bundle update rails
```

bundle executed successfully then I executed command:

```
Step2: rails app:update
```

For multiple files option I get like:

```
/config/boot.rb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdhm] n
```

> conflict  config/boot.rb and I selected 'n' every time.

I am getting error like:

```
create  bin/yarn
remove  bin/yarn
rails  active_storage:update
#<Thread:0x00007fde6d251b30@/Users/bbhushan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/thread-inheritable_attributes-2.0.0/lib/thread/inheritable_attributes.rb:10 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from /Users/bbhushan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/thread-inheritable_attributes-2.0.0/lib/thread/inheritable_attributes.rb:12:in `block in initialize'
    1: from /Users/bbhushan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:339:in `block in spawn_thread'
/Users/bbhushan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:339:in `sleep': can't convert Array into time interval (TypeError)
rails aborted!
NameError: wrong constant name [[:error, ["detected unsupported rails version 6.0.1"], nil]]
```

I am not able to fix it, please help.

Answer (score 0):

First issue is that upgrading from 5.0 to 6.0 is not officially supported by Rails. You first need to upgrade to 5.1, then to 5.2, and finally to 6.0.

Another issue is here:

> conflict config/boot.rb and I selected 'n' every time.

You rather need to select 'y' to switch Rails internal files to the 6.0 versions.

Attention: This could overwrite modifications you made before, so I'd recommend to review these changes in your version control system.

Comment: Why upgrading from rails 5.0 to rails 6.0 is not supported directly ?

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#the-upgrade-process